# Removing Get variables from something stored in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

So I am working with a system right now that sometimes accidentally stores Get variables, for example I have
http://twitter.com/jayzalowitz?uid=439367642&iid=fa3166d9-5035-4d8c-bdc8-3af3b8f0b15d&nid=12+22+20120726
instead of http://twitter.com/jayzalowitz

Is there a method by which one could strip all GET variables out in mysql?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Sorry, I totally misunderstood the problem you were trying to solve.

How about this:

```
mysql> SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('http://twitter.com/jayzalowitz?uid=439367642&iid=fa3166d9-5035-4d8c-bdc8-3af3b8f0b15d&nid=12+22+20120726', '?', 1) AS shorter_string;
+--------------------------------+
| shorter_string                 |
+--------------------------------+
| http://twitter.com/jayzalowitz |
+--------------------------------+
```

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index for docs.